# Graylog content pack -> get fields

Tags: graylog2

I have installed graylog to analyse the logs of my haproxy better. I've installed to content pack, and now I can see the haproxy logs flowing in. However, the log message is 1 string. I'm trying to substract the different fields which are defined in the content pack (https://github.com/Graylog2/graylog-contentpack-haproxy/blob/master/content_pack.json): Remote Address, server, .... How can I do this?

Thanks!

[image: Graylog screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those looking for the same:

- Create an input
- Manage extractors
- Add an extractor

  Type: Regular expression

  Source: Message
  [image]